# comparing values using C# and inserting row IF true

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, arrays, case

I have the follow code which will randomly assign 6 numbers to my array.

```
public void LottoWinners(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Dictionary<int, int> number = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Random generator = new Random();
    while (number.Count < 6)
    {
        number[generator.Next(1, 49)] = 1;
    }

    string[] lotto = number.Keys.OrderBy(n => n).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();

    //write some logic to find out who has 3 match numbers 
    //and assign there ticket to the winners table tblWinners

}
```

I need to then compare the values in the array with the values in the tblTickets table to see who the winners are. HOWEVER i need to break down the winners:

So if they have 3 matching numbers then insert there ticketID into the tblWinners table.

I was thinking about writing a case statement but how do check for equality?

The problem is i hold my values in the table like this:

```
tblLotto(val0,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5)
```

So i need to search my table using some sort of logic....

My players class looks like this:

public class players
{
    public void LottoDraw(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connectionstring = "Server=C;Database=lotto;User Id=lottoadmin;Password=password;";

```
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))  // Create connection with automatic disposal
    {
        con.Open();

        // Create new DataTable
        DataTable player = new DataTable();
        {
            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 LOTTOID, VAL0, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4, VAL5 FROM tblLotto ORDER BY NEWID()", con))

            {
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                a.Fill(player);
            }


            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: any reasons for using a dictionary to hold the numbers?

Comment: @Lojko: no it is not...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) to find the items that two collections have in common, and then apply [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) to see if the intersection has at least three items:

```
var winners = players.
    Where(player => player.Numbers.Intersect(lotto).Count() >= 3);
```

A couple of notes on your implementation:

- Rather than using a `Dictionary` and setting values to `1`, use a `HashSet`: you are interested in keys, not values, so a `Set` would be more appropriate
- Do not convert numbers to strings until you need to display them; searching for numbers is best done with a collection of numbers.
- If you use a set, the selection can be rewritten as follows:

---

```
var lotto = new HashSet<int>(...); // put six numbers here
var winners = players.
    Where(player => player.Numbers.Where(n => lotto.Contains(n)).Count() >= 3);
```

**EDIT :** (in response to an edit of the question) Your `Player` class contains player's numbers as separate attributes. You can add a way of retrieving them as a collection by adding a property `Numbers`, like this:

```
class Player {
    ...
    public int val0, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6;
    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers {
        get {
            return new[] {val0, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PriceCheaperton I made an assumption that your program has some way of knowing what numbers each player has selected; it wouldn't work without that knowledge.

Comment: I see.. So i need some sort of class to retrieve the player numbers.

Comment: No, you've got somewhere your players, haven't you? So just load them to a List or whatever.

Comment: I have added my players class to the original post. But i get the message: `'Lotto.players' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Comment: wow thanks.. you are kind. Await modification to your post :)

Comment: I am not using an HashSet and just going with your first intersect code. But i still get the error: **'Lotto.players' does not contain a definition for 'Where'**

Comment: @PriceCheaperton You need to use `System.Linq` for that.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton `players` needs to be defined as an `IEnumerable<Player>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do condition (add using System.Linq):

```
UsersNumbers.Intersect(GeneratedNumbers).Count() >= 3
```

Comment: How do i define what `UserNumbers` is?

Comment: You should add this condition to Where clause as @dasblinkenlight has shown.